# math.cbrt 10x slower than **(1/3)

Tags: python

With Python 3.11, there is a new way of computing the cubic root, but it is significantly slower than the old way. Am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not really measuring how fast `cbrt` is, you're measuring function call overhead.

```
# python -m timeit -s 'cbrt = lambda x: x ** (1/3)' 'cbrt(131)'
5000000 loops, best of 5: 73.3 nsec per loop
# python -m timeit -s 'from math import cbrt' 'cbrt(131)'
5000000 loops, best of 5: 54.2 nsec per loop
```

Furthermore, [`math.cbrt` is defined](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2844aa6a8eb1d486b5c432f0ed33a2082998f41e/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1214-L1216) as an alias for the underlying C library's `cbrt` function ([libc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cbrt.3.html), [windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/cbrt-cbrtf-cbrtl?view=msvc-170), ...) which could be fast, could be slow, could be accurate, could be inaccurate, on your platform.

Check whether your userland `cbrt` and `math.cbrt` return exactly the same result – chances are they don't:

```
Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 26 2022, 03:01:09) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> my_cbrt = lambda x: x ** (1/3)
>>> from math import cbrt
>>> cbrt(123) - my_cbrt(123)
8.881784197001252e-16
>>>
```

Comment: If the function call overhead is so large compared to the speed of the operation itself, doesn't it still imply we shouldn't use `cbrt`?

Comment: @Stuart It doesn't really matter. For a single call, 54 nanoseconds isn't much, and when you need to do it a whole bunch, you'd opt for NumPy anyway.

Comment: Well so basically, you'd never use `cbrt`?

Comment: What do you mean by `Check whether your userland cbrt and math.cbrt return exactly the same result – chances are they don't`. I'm sorry I'm not familiar with it, fairly new user here.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Edited into answer.

Comment: They do return the same answer on my end :/ https://i.imgur.com/RvmastC.png

Comment: (I've checked there is no rounding up https://i.imgur.com/Aga89hF.png)

Comment: So I'm not sure when would one even bother use `cbrt`

Comment: As you can see from my edit, there _is_ a difference on the platform I tried, which is what I referred to in my answer. "When would one bother to use cbrt"? How would you implement (toy example) `def compute_and_multiply(func, x, a): return func(x) * a` so you'd be able to plug in any single-argument `func`? ;-)

Comment: Ohh in that case using a `lambda` function would have the call overhead too and `math.cbrt` would be faster?

Comment: Exactly. `x ** (1/3)` might be faster as an inline expression, but `math.cbrt` (implemented in C) is faster as a function than anything you can concoct in Python "userland".